# Console2 Tab for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-10, console2

I can't get Console2 to give me a new tab with the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows shell.  So far, I've tried:

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"
```

The first two commands work from Start > Run. None of them work as a new tab command in Console2.

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't see the connection with Ubuntu in your issue... neither with Bash... it's seems to only be a gui issue on Windows (with console2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Console2 version.

**You need to install 64bits version of Console2**. You can find it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/console-devel/2.00/). You will see Console-2.00b148-Beta_64bit.zip. Install as usual.

In Console2 (64 bits) you must go to menu *Edit ->Settings...* and then in *"Startup dir"* you can choose "C:\Users\your_user_name". Finally in *"Shell"* write "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe". And pick OK.

Comment: Works, thanks! It looks like the combination of 64-bit and `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` as a command for a new tab was what I needed. The Startup Dir and Shell changes didn't seem to have any effect.